# Object showing only in render and not in viewport even though visibility settings are correct

Tags: 3d-view, fluid-simulation, visibility

The fluid sim obstacle is visible at the top of the monitor. Before this render I turned made sure that render visibility was set to off.

[image]

Viewport view, the obstacle is invisible whilst the visibility is on.

[image]

Something very strange I have noticed is that if I delete the object and then begin to render a frame the object is still present. I haven't a clue what could be causing this.

Perhaps this has something to do with the objects parent/child tree?

Edit:
I have managed to make the obstacle visible in the viewport, however I am still stuck with the issue of it always showing up in my render.

Blend file is included now.

[image]

Comment: It might be easier to find the solution if you upload your .blend file. https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 1):

You've got a second object, called Obstacle.001, which is hidden in viewport but not in render. It's a child of "Monitor" (maybe that's why you didn't seen it in the outliner, you need to expand "Monitor" to see it).